# Heroku deploying - Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: javascript, git, heroku, three.js

I'm trying to deploying my 3d game (created using three.js) on heroku server. But after a command "git push heroku master" I get the following problem:

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 252, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (251/251), done.
Writing objects: 100% (252/252), 2.38 MiB | 89.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 252 (delta 55), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:infinite-woodland-7676.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:infinite-woodland-7676.git'
```

Link to repository --> https://github.com/mkkroliks/Snake3d

I'am not experienced in using heroku so it might be simple solution, but I can't find any on the web.

Comment: Seems like you are missing some key files which heroku needs to identify your app and app type

Comment: When I was deploying node app I had Procfile...But don't think it's necessary in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add either a `Procfile` that describes how to run your application, or a `package.json` file that describes the dependencies, so that Heroku can determine what kind of application this is and compile it accordingly.

Something like:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile

or

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#declare-app-dependencies

Comment: Problem solved ;) I created server using nodejs which will start my app and then created Procfile and everything works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there are four potential problems.

**First**, you need to make sure that you have the Procfile that is capable of executing your script. It should contain something like this:

node server.js

**Second**, you need to make sure that your `package.json` has all the necessary dependencies listed along with the `npm` start key. To ensure make sure that all your dependencies are loaded, delete your node_modules folder, run `"npm install --production"`, then try to run your app. If you are missing any dependencies you will get a missing module error.

**Third**, make sure that your app works in `heroku's` environment. Run "foreman start web" in your command line in the directory with the `Procfile`, and then check out your site at `localhost:5000.`

**The fourth** probably source of error (and the error that I ran into) is that all these files (`Procfile and package.json`) need to be in the git root directory. Foreman can run even if these files are not in the root directory, so just double check.